# Can I convert Base64 string into HttpPostedFileBase object?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an live image from my webcam, and I send that image to my controller via an `AJAX`request.

```html
<div id="container">
  <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="350"></canvas>
  <button onclick="setInterval(snapshot, 6000)">Click</button>
</div>
```

```js
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true
  }).then(function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
  });
}

function snapshot() {
  // Draws current image from the video element into the canvas
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var imgInfo = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  console.log(imgInfo);
  var image = imgInfo; // to create a image read the previous example

  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("action","controller")',
    data: { base64: image },
    type: "post",
    complete: function() {
      console.log("Ready");
    }
  });
}
```

Now in the controller I want to convert this `base64` string into `HttpPostedFileBase` object. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but do it server side in your C# code, not JS. [`Convert.FromBase64String()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.8) will give you a `byte[]` you can store wherever required.

Comment: Why you need the `HttpPostedFileBase` here? You can just convert the base64 string to byte[] and that will give you ContentLength, InputStream, contentType you already know.